# Passing multiple arguments to apply (Python)

Tags: python, apply, dataframe

I'm trying to clean up some code in Python to vectorize a set of features and I'm wondering if there's a good way to use apply to pass multiple arguments. Consider the following (current version):

```
def function_1(x):
    if "string" in x:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['newFeature'] = df['oldFeature'].apply(function_1)
```

With the above I'm having to write a new function (function_1, function_2, etc) to test for each substring `"string"` that I want to find. In an ideal world I could combine all of these redundant functions and use something like this:

```
def function(x, string):
    if string in x:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['newFeature'] = df['existingFeature'].apply(function("string"))
```

But trying that returns the error `TypeError: function() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` Is there another way to accomplish the same thing?

### **Edit:**

```
def function(string, x):
    if string in x:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['newFeature'] = df['oldFeature'].apply(partial(function, 'string'))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you want [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial).  A demo:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def mult(a, b):
...     return a * b
...
>>> doubler = partial(mult, 2)
>>> doubler(4)
8
```

In your case you need to swap arguments in `function` (because of idea of `partial`), and then just

```
df['existingFeature'].apply(partial(function, "string"))
```

Comment: Or he could simply use a `lambda`: `doubler = lambda b: mult(b, 2)`. With a `lambda` you can fix whatever values you want, while `partial` can only fix positional arguments as they are specified.

Comment: In many cases, you can specify keyword arguments: `partial(mult, a=5)` or `partial(mult, b=5)`. (This does require you to know the names of the arguments, which may not be documented.)