# python pandas: apply a function with arguments to a series. Update

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I would like to apply a function with argument to a pandas series: I have found two different solution of SO:

[python pandas: apply a function with arguments to a series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182744/python-pandas-apply-a-function-with-arguments-to-a-series)

and

[Passing multiple arguments to apply (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140035/passing-multiple-arguments-to-apply-python)

both of them rely on the use of `functool.partial` and they works absolutely fine. By the way the new version of Pandas support multiple argument: in any case I do not understand how does it works. Example:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2],'y':[10,20]})
a['x'].apply(lambda x,y: x+y, args=(100))
```

It exits with a:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() argument after * must be a sequence, not int
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `TypeError` is saying that you passed the wrong type to the `lambda` function `x + y`. It's expecting the `args` to be a sequence, but it got an `int`. You may have thought that `(100)` was a tuple (a sequence), but in python it's the comma that makes a tuple:

```
In [10]: type((100))
Out[10]: int

In [11]: type((100,))
Out[11]: tuple
```

So change your last line to

```
In [12]: a['x'].apply(lambda x, y: x + y, args=(100,))
Out[12]: 
0    101
1    102
Name: x, dtype: int64
```