# Using apply in pandas data frame gives ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a vector that I want to apply a pearson correlation to all rows of a pandas data frame.  I am trying the following:

```
df.apply(apply_func, axis=1, args=(np.array([1,2,3])), raw=True)
```

Apply func simply takes two `numpy` arrays and calculates the correlation

```
def apply_func(v1, v2):
     #do stuff
```

However I get the following error when I try to run this

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I've set breakpoints in `apply_func` and I never get inside it.  I'm sure I'm using this structure incorrectly but I'm not sure what it is.  I would think that each row of `df` would be passed to `apply_func` as the first positional argument, and whatever is in `args` would take up the rest.  Is this not correct?

**EDIT** I have created a simple example below, in this example the `apply_func` function should just add the two vectors.  Still creates the same errors

```
data = {'k1': [1, 2, 3], 'k2': [4, 5, 6], 'k3': [7, 8, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def apply_func(v1, v2):
    return v1 + v2
df.apply(apply_func, axis=1, args=(np.array([1,2,3])), raw=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So was able to solve my own question by finding the following post

[python pandas: apply a function with arguments to a series. Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188504/python-pandas-apply-a-function-with-arguments-to-a-series-update)

My particular situation produced a different error (no idea why) but their solution worked.  By changing

```
args=(np.array([1,2,3]))
```

to

```
args=(np.array([1,2,3]),)  #<-- NOTE THE COMMA
```

I ensure that args is a tuple which is what the `apply` function is expecting and I get the result I was expecting