# How to get very first word before and after 'text'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am after the very first word before v and after 'v'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["cans choc v macroni ice", 
                            "chocolate sundaes v chocolate ice cream", 
                            "Chocolate v sauce"]})
```

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
cans choc v macroni ice
chocolate sundaes v chocolate ice cream
Chocolate v sauce
```

I want it to look like:

```
cans v macroni
chocolate v chocolate
Chocolate v sauce
```

How can this be achieved in pandas?  The common element is 'v'.

Comment: can you please clarify which words you are looking to extract as your first example conflicts with your second.

Comment: Yes, @Will is correct.  You say that you want the ***FIRST*** word after each `v`, which means that the first entry should say `cans v macroni`, instead of `cans v ice`, as you've written.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson Actually I need cans v ice. Terrible miscommunication on my part.

Comment: @gerrybro Your second example should be "chocolate v cream" if your first is "cans v ice", no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df.text.str.split('v', expand=True)\
  .apply(lambda x: x.str.extract('(\w+)', expand=False))\
  .apply(lambda x: ' v '.join(x), 1)
```

Output:

```
0           cans v macroni
1    chocolate v chocolate
2        Chocolate v sauce
```

Comment: TypeError: ('sequence item 2: expected str instance, float found', 'occurred at index 2') -   .apply(lambda x: ' v '.join(x), 1)

Comment: What does your data look like? You migh need to do a astype(str) in one of those lines to force casting as string.  Can you generate a data set that produces this error?

Comment: For: df1['A'].str.split('v', expand=True)\
  .apply(lambda x: x.str.extract('(\w+)', expand=False))\
  .apply(lambda x: ' v '.join(x), 1)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you cannot use the split function and then map the function to the column?

As per the first example, this will work:

```
def word_scrape(whole_string):
    outside_v = whole_string.split(" v ")
    first_word = outside_v[0].split(" ")[0]
    last_word = outside_v[1].split(" ")[1]
    return first_word + " v " + last_word

for i,text in enumerate(df.ix[:,'text']):
    df.ix[i,'text'] = word_scrape(text)
```

for fault tolerance for single word entries, use:

```
def word_scrape(whole_string):
    try:
        outside_v = whole_string.split(" v ")
        first_word = outside_v[0].split(" ")[0]
        last_word = outside_v[1].split(" ")[1]
        return first_word + " v " + last_word
    except: 
        outside_v = whole_string.split(" v ")
        first_word = outside_v[0].split(" ")[0]
        last_word = outside_v[1].split(" ")[0]
        return first_word + " v " + last_word

for i,text in enumerate(df.ix[:,'text']):
    df.ix[i,'text'] = word_scrape(text)
```

As per the second example, this will work:

```
def word_scrape(whole_string):
    outside_v = whole_string.split(" v ")
    first_word = outside_v[0].split(" ")[0]
    last_word = outside_v[1].split(" ")[0]
    return first_word + " v " + last_word

for i,text in enumerate(df.ix[:,'text']):
    df.ix[i,'text'] = word_scrape(text)
```

Comment: This does not give desired output

Comment: Does this not give you "cans v ice"? (which FYI are the first and last words, not both the first words)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions, as @James suggests.  But here's another way, using `pandas` `apply`, which more generically handles the question at hand.

(BTW, there are several very similar questions and answers, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33204763/how-to-pass-multiple-arguments-to-the-apply-function).)

```
>>> def my_fun(my_text, my_sep):
>>>   vals = my_text.split(my_sep)
>>>   vals = [val.split()[0] for val in vals]
>>>   return vals

>>> df.text.apply(lambda my_text: my_fun(my_text, 'v'))
```

Of course, please use better names than this!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a regular expression to the string operations on the `text` columns.

```
df.text.str.extract(r'(\w+ v \w+)', expand=True)

# returns:
                     0
0       choc v macroni
1  sundaes v chocolate
2    Chocolate v sauce
```

Comment: Why is it reading sundaes v chocolate?  I'm wanting chocolate v chocolate?

Comment: Ok.  How is the computer supposed to distinguish which word you want?  In other words, why is `chocolate` important, but `sundaes` is not?  In your question, you ask how to get the **first word before and after 'v'**.

Comment: I do not need that data.